# Disable .hover for a set amount of time

Tags: jquery, animation, hover, sprite

**tl;dr** -> *sprite animation on mouseover (done), rewind animation on mouseleave (done), disable hover while animation is playing.(needs solving)* - **[FIDDLE with me](http://jsfiddle.net/8nFu5/1/)**

I have a rather specific problem with my menu and since my knowledge of javascript is limited at best I thought you could help me. I wanted to have an animation playing while the user hovers over it and have it return to it's original state when the mouse leaves the button. While I got this working with the help of a script called spritely I ran into a usability problem.

The code will register multiple mouseovers even while the animation is playing. This leads to strange behaviour where the animation would freeze at certain frames.

I tried to counter this with `hoverIntent`, a script that tries to guess the users intent and only calls the `.hover` if he moves the mouse a set amount of pixels in an interval. This works fine for certain bugs, but kills the interactivity and with that, the purpose of the animation.

I thought about a variable counting down from 1000ms to 1ms and tie the functions to this variable but failed miserably.

Since I really want this to work, I turn to you, hivemind. In a nutshell I want to have the button not register any `.hover` for around a second (`endAnimationDelay`) until the Animation is finished. Any help or advise which route to go would be appreciated by me.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
var fps = 25;
var playFrames = 25;
var frames = 25;
var endAnimationDelay = ((fps / playFrames) * 1000);

    function playAnimationAbout() {
        $('#about').sprite({
            fps: fps,
            no_of_frames: frames,
            play_frames: playFrames
        });
    }

    function playAnimationAboutBack() {
        $('#about').sprite({
            fps: fps,
            no_of_frames: frames,
            play_frames: playFrames,
            rewind: true
        });
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#about').destroy();
        }, endAnimationDelay);
    }

$('#about').hoverIntent(playAnimationAbout, playAnimationAboutBack);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, by adding and removing a set of classes that indicate wether the animation was playing or on wich frame it was. **[fixed FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8nFu5/7/)**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
var fps = 25;
var playFrames = 25;
var frames = 25;
var endAnimationDelay = ((fps / playFrames) * 1000);


function playAnimationAbout() {
    if ($('#about').hasClass('playing')) {} else if ($('#about').hasClass('end')) {
        $('#about').sprite({
            fps: fps,
            no_of_frames: frames,
            play_frames: playFrames,
            rewind: true
        });
        $('#about').addClass('playing');
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#about').destroy();
            $('#about').removeClass('end');
            $('#about').removeClass('playing');
            $('#about').addClass('start');
        }, endAnimationDelay);
    } else {
        if ($('#about').hasClass('start')) {
            $('#about').removeClass('start');
        }
        $('#about').sprite({
            fps: fps,
            no_of_frames: frames,
            play_frames: playFrames
        });

        $('#about').addClass('playing');
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#about').addClass('end');
            $('#about').removeClass('playing');
        }, endAnimationDelay);
    }
}

function playAnimationAboutBack() {
    if ($('#about').hasClass('playing')) {} else if ($('#about').hasClass('start')) {} else {
        if ($('#about').hasClass('end')) {
            $('#about').removeClass('end');
        }
        $('#about').sprite({
            fps: fps,
            no_of_frames: frames,
            play_frames: playFrames,
            rewind: true
        });
        $('#about').addClass('playing');
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#about').destroy();
        }, endAnimationDelay);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#about').addClass('start');
            $('#about').removeClass('playing');
        }, endAnimationDelay);
    }

}

$('#about').hoverIntent(playAnimationAbout, playAnimationAboutBack); });
```